# How to reference controllers in Swift (MVC)

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

I have a single window application. Currently I have one xib file (MainMenu.xib) and I have one .swift file (AppDelegate).

If I want to add controls to the UI and assign specific controllers to some of those UI components to to handle additional functionality in a separate file e.g. a NSTextView with a TextViewController - how would I obtain a reference to TextViewController, from within my AppDelegate?

Most tutorials stop short from this and assume that everybody will want to use @IBOutlets to access a controls' properties from the AppDelegate.

I know you can use segues (prepareForSegue) - but my application does not make use of storyboards, and I would like to understand the MVC implementation within cocoa a little better.

Comment: your question reflects a minimal understanding the domain which is OK, but please go and spend a week or so doing tutorials and coding cocoa and then see if you can refine your question or if you even need to ask it anymore.

Comment: Thats funny because I've spend an entire week reading book(s), watching tutorials and making a hell of a lot of 'hello world' apps.

Comment: UI elements such as the NSTextView can have its own Controller, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any object can can have its own controller. The `AppDelegate` is not a holy grail, its just an object which implements methods in the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol. Its not a universal switchboard for everything you might wish to connect.

Some of the tutorials do a starting Cocoa dev great disservice by using the AppDelegate as a quick and nasty place to put things. For a storyboard app this all that needs to be contained in the class which conforms to `NSApplicationDelegate`

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

}
```

i.e nothing.

A nominal pattern is *one screen has one controller* but even that isn't true when you use embedding patterns to control subviews within one window. However consider the simple `Cocoa Application` project template

[image]

The `ViewController` class is a subclass of `NSViewController` and is where you might be placing the `IBOutlet` to your `NSTextView` and some of the logic to do with interacting with it in that context.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController,NSTextDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textView: NSTextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureTextController()
    }

    var textController:TextFieldInteractionManager!
    func configureTextController() {
        //textcontroller can be local var , alternatively inject it into this VC
        textController =  TextFieldInteractionManager(textView)
    }


}
```

If you have specific interactions that you want to do across the entire project you might want to place these in another class say `TextFieldInteractionManager` and make that the delegate of the text field. You would pass the text field to the manager class when you construct the view controller.

The hypothetical `TextFieldInteractionManager` might be created locally or injected in during the setup of the `ViewController` instance i.e `prepareForSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender sender: AnyObject?)`. The possibilities are varied and will depend on the scope of your app and how you wish to manage your references.

My commonly used pattern is to have a **Root** view controller which passes references down the to the next controller in the chain. YMMV

[Dependancy Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is a good pattern to know about.

[Massive View Controller](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/267213/massive-view-controller-ios-solutions) is a good anti-pattern to know about and avoid.

This is what I meant when i said go and get some domain knowledge. Its an expanding tree of stuff to learn about and why your question as its stands is not a good fit for SO.

Comment: Thanks Warren, this is exactly what I meant. There's a lot of focus on the AppDelegate even though it doesn't fit into the MVC pattern. I'm fully aware of the DI pattern and was even investigating the Typhoon DI framework. However I do not want to go this route just yet - most projects (because of their size) do not warrant additional frameworks.

If you have as many as two controllers sitting behind the same View (where the view inherits from NSView etc) then you need a way to obtain a reference to all those controllers in use.

This is what I'm after.

Comment: So in other words. In the code you've given for the ViewController - In my app that NSTextView (which is a subview) has a controller of its own. So if I want to call functions on that controller or implement the observer pattern (using KVC) how would I obtain that reference from ViewController.

Comment: Thank Warren. I appreciate the time you took explaining. I like the root view controller you use. I've also found that one can [use delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH8-SW1) to facilitate communication between controllers.

Comment: Yes , exactly.  delegation is the best pattern for chatting back up or across  the controller stack. Try to avoid `Singleton` pattern and `NSNotification` where you can.  Good luck :-)